# Changing the values of pointers via addresses

Tags: c++, arrays

This week, we were tasked to create a program where:

- Program displays the addresses and values of the array
- User inputs the corresponding address he wants to change
- User inputs the new value for that address

I was able to figure how a pointer works but it displays another number instead of the inputted value.
[image: Results]

Here's the code:

```
int j =1, var, nx;
int array[4] = {3618, 6555, 5012, 1869};
int* pa; //pointer
char choice;
int remember = 0;
pa = array; 

cout << endl;
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t\t Values" << endl;
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    cout << "\tarray" << j;
    cout << " = " << std::dec << *(pa + i);
    cout << " (" << pa + i << ")" << endl;
    j++;
}
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl << endl;

cout << "\tPlease enter an address: ";
cin >> hex >>var;
cout << endl;
cout <<"\tYou entered: " << hex << var << endl;

cout << "\tPlease enter a new value: ";
cin >> nx;

pa = (int*)var; 
cout << endl;
*pa = nx; 
pa = array; 

j=1;
cout << endl;
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t\t New Values" << endl;
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    cout << "\tarray" << j;
    cout << " = " << std::dec << *(pa+i);
    cout << " (" << &array[i] << ")" << endl;
    j++;
}
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `cin >> nx;` is reading the value as hex. I'm quite sure this is happening because the previous use of `cin` in the program read the value as hex: `cin >> hex >>var;`. I observed the same thing happening with a `cout` statement I added to your program when testing it.

If that is changed to `cin >> std::dec >> nx;`, the behavior of the program is correct.

E.g., using your test run: 353 in hex when converted to decimal is 851.

A helpful tip for future: You don't need the `j` variable: inside the `for` loops you can just use `i + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

A good habit to get into is to use descriptive words as your variables. It makes it a whole lot easier to debug, and more importantly understand what is going on.

Now, if I'm interpreting this correctly, you are setting `pa` equal to a new pointer called `var`, instead of setting `pa` equal to `var`. [Here is a reference page on pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), Scroll to the dereference operator to see what I was talking about. The (int*) is unnecessary.

Comment: Noted! The (int*) is placed to force pa to be compatible with the variable type int*. Without it, an error "incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int*" would display.

Answer (score 0):

What OP is seeing is the the `hex` modifier still being in effect.

```
cin >> hex >>var;
```

turns on `hex`. Nothing turned it off again.

So when OP types in 353, the program interprets it as a hexadecimal number. 0x353 == 851.

Solution:

Revert to decimal input.

```
cin >> dec >> nx;
```